# Resizing and line breaking for individual matrix entries

Tags: line-breaking, matrices

[image: That's what I am looking to enter]

To make things easy, I have put up a pic here, I do not understand how I can reduce the size of the long entries in the matrix (the diagonal entries primarily) and also introduce line breaks so as to print a matrix similar to this one here.

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks and regards, 
Florian

Comment: welcome to tex.sx, It always helps if you post a complete small document showing the problem, If you provided a matrix with that data, someone could show you how to reformat it.

Answer (score 9):

Environment `smallmatrix` of package `amsmath` provides a matrix with smaller fonts and manual line breaks, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  \mathbf{A}^{-1} = \frac{1}{\alpha}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \begin{smallmatrix}
      \lambda_c \lambda_m \lambda_s + \lambda_m \lambda_s + {} \\
      E^2 \lambda_c \lambda_s + E_y^2 \lambda_c \lambda_m
    \end{smallmatrix} &
    -E_x E_y \lambda_c \lambda_m &
    E_x E \lambda_c \lambda_s &
    E_x \lambda_m \lambda_s
    \\
    -E_x E_y \lambda_c \lambda_m &
    \begin{smallmatrix}
      \lambda_c \lambda_m \lambda_s + \lambda_m \lambda_s + {} \\
      E^2 \lambda_c \lambda_s + E_z^2 \lambda_c \lambda_m
    \end{smallmatrix} &
    E_y E \lambda_c \lambda_s &
    E_y \lambda_m \lambda_s
    \\
    E_x E \lambda_c \lambda_s &
    E_y E \lambda_c \lambda_s &
    \begin{smallmatrix}
      \lambda_s^2 + {} \\
      (E_z^2 + E_y^2 + \lambda_s) \lambda_c \lambda_s
    \end{smallmatrix} &
    -E \lambda_s^2
    \\
    E_x \lambda_m \lambda_s &
    E_y \lambda_m \lambda_s &
    -E \lambda_s^2 &
    \begin{smallmatrix}
      E^2 \lambda_s^2 + {} \\
      (E_x^2 + E_y^2 + \lambda_s) \lambda_m \lambda_s
    \end{smallmatrix}
  \end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: +1 for the effort of typing all that in without a supplied example:-)